# How to display a call timer (elapsed time) on video chat Opentok - Cordova

Tags: cordova, opentok

First of all, I'm not sure if there's a built in call timer in Opentok. I tried searching the docs but can't find any. So I've opted for a native JavaScript sol'n by creating a function that starts the counting (client-side) as soon the video starts rendering..

```
function startCallTimer(){
    $interval(function(){ 
        var myTime = $scope.elapsed;
        var ss = myTime.split(":");
        var dt = new Date();
        dt.setHours(ss[0]);
        dt.setMinutes(ss[1]);
        dt.setSeconds(ss[2]); 
        var dt2 = new Date(dt.valueOf() + 1000);
        var ts = dt2.toTimeString().split(" ")[0];    
        $scope.elapsed = ts;
    }, 1000); 
  }
```

The timer looks ok and working. The problem starts when the video starts rendering. The call timer disappears.

My call timer is positioned on the top right corner of the page with a style of..

```
.call-timer{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width:100px;
    z-index:100 !important;
}
```

Questions:

1. Is there a built-in call timer in Opentok that I do not know of?
2. If the above question is false, then what is the best way to add a call timer?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the counter on a mobile device using Cordova, you most know that the OpenTok video is not rendering as HTML. The cam is loaded on-top-of the Cordova Webview.

z-index will not help in anyway. You can only display timers/buttons or what so ever outside the video container.

Also see next issues about this:

- https://github.com/songz/cordova-plugin-opentok/issues/120
- https://github.com/songz/cordova-plugin-opentok/issues/133

Comment: Hi Mark. I've already read in the forums and github that the video is not actually part of the HTML Dom but I was still hoping that manipulating the html structure with the right css would fix it. I guess that's not the case though. So now, my question is, is there any way to draw or position an element above the video? Right now, I was able to put the timer on top of the video as a work around but I would want to position my buttons (hung up, reconnect etc..) on top of the video. Thanks!

Comment: It isn't possible to draw any HTML on top of the TokBox video. Nor is it possible to have the TokBox video behind the WebView or any other HTML. At this moment of writing. At this moment you must place all your buttons outside the video

Comment: Hi Mark, I really appreciate your help but if possible, can you provide some links or references? Sorry, I'm just new with Opentok and I'm not very familiar with how the IOS work behind the scenes. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: See my updated question with references to issues on GitHub. And believe me, we have been struggling for a while with it and the video is just natively loaded on top of the Webview and it doesn't consider any changes to `z-index`.